# How to use the sinon stubs placed in separate files in different test suites

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai, sinon, stub

I am organizing stubs by placing them in a separate folder as separate file like:

```
test
 |_____ create.test.js
 |_____ dochelp.test.js
stubs
 |_____ input.js
```

Here is the code for input.js stub

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const input = require('../../utils/input');


module.exports = sinon.stub(input, 'getInput')
```

Here is the code in create.test.js

```
const inputStub = require('./stubs/input');
inputStub.resolves(true);

describe('suite', () => {
   //... same code is in dochelp.test.js
   after(() => {
      inputStub.restore();
   })
})
```

As the require caches the module once resolved so whenever another test file requires the stub file, it will return the cache module, and so the cache which was previously used by create.test.js file is returned and by the time it is finished it restores the stub so in another test file it is normal non-stub function again.

How can stubs be kept in the separate file  and reused again in other test files.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the module registry - the cache of the required module. So, you can delete the key from the [require.cache](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache) object in mocha `before` hook.

> Modules are cached in this object when they are required. By deleting a key value from this object, the next `require` will reload the module.

A complete working example:

`test/create.test.js`:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
const { resetModule } = require('../utils/test');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const { expect } = chai;

describe('create test suite', () => {
  let inputStub;
  before(() => {
    resetModule();
    inputStub = require('../stubs/input');
    inputStub.resolves(true);
  });
  after(() => {
    inputStub.restore();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    await expect(inputStub()).to.eventually.be.true;
  });
});
```

`test/dochelp.test.js`:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
const { resetModule } = require('../utils/test');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const { expect } = chai;

describe('dochelp test suite', () => {
  let inputStub;
  before(() => {
    resetModule();
    inputStub = require('../stubs/input');
    inputStub.resolves(false);
  });
  after(() => {
    inputStub.restore();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    await expect(inputStub()).to.eventually.be.false;
  });
});
```

`utils/input.js`:

```js
const input = {
  async getInput() {
    return 'real input';
  },
};

module.exports = input;
```

`utils/test.js`:

```js
function resetModule() {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('../stubs/input')];
}

module.exports = { resetModule };
```

`stubs/input.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const input = require('../utils/input');

module.exports = sinon.stub(input, 'getInput');
```

unit test result:

```
⚡  npx mocha ./test/*.test.js


  create test suite
    ✓ should pass

  dochelp test suite
    ✓ should pass


  2 passing (469ms)
```